# Jquery UI datepicker renders in every tr except the last

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a piece of jquery code that gets dynamically called, and generates any number of tr tags.  In each tr tag I have an input of type text set to the jquery ui datepicker.  The datepicker will render in every tr tag except the last one consistently no matter how many tr tags are generated. What am I missing?  Here is the responsible jquery code:

```
// create order row
var addOrderRow = function(id, name) {
var self = this;
self.Name = name;
self.Id = id;


self.Output = "<tr><th>Code</th><th>Product</th><th>Options</th><th>Size</th><th>Package</th>" +
    "<th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Delivery Date</th></tr>" +
    "<tr><td><select name='prodCode'></select></td><td><select name='product'></select>" +
    "</td><td><select name='options'></select></td><td><select name='size'></select></td><td>" +
    "<select name='package'></select></td><td><select name='price'></select></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' name='quantity'></input></td><td><input type='text' " +
    "name='deliverDate'></input>" +
    "</td></tr>";

// assign datepicker to deliverDate
$(function() {
    $("input[name=deliverDate]").datepicker({minDate: 0});
});

// populate product code
getPcodeProducts();

return self.Output;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be actually calling the function you use to assign the datepicker. Not to mention, "deliverDate" won't be available to assign to until you add the output to the DOM. So that function needs to come after whatever you're calling to fire the addOrderRow. But then, you'll need some way to actually target it if there are multiple rows with the same name. Concatenate the "id" parameter in the name field in your output, then call your function, add your output code to the page and do:

```
$("input[name=deliverDate"+id+"]").datepicker({minDate: 0});
```

in what I assume is a for loop you're doing this in.

Added example for question in comment. Note: I don't have time to test this, you might have to tweak it a bit, but this is the general idea:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addOrderRow(id, name)
        {
            return "<tr><td><input type='text' name='deliverDate'"+id+"'></input><input type='button' name='cmd'"+id+"' onclick='processRowUpdate(\'"+id+"\');'></input></td></tr>";
        }
        function processRowUpdate(id)
        {
            var deliverDate = $("input[name=deliverDate"+id+"]").val();
            alert(deliverDate);
        }
        var arrOrders = [{name:"name1", id:"1"}, {name:"name2", id:"2"}];

        for (var i = 0; i < arrOrder.length; i++)
        {
            $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(addOrderRow(arrOrder[i].name, arrOrder[i].id));
            $("input[name=deliverDate"+id+"]").datepicker({minDate: 0});
        }
    </script
</head>
<body>
    <table id="orders"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, I've now been trying to implement an independent name or id for each input, but since these inputs are dynamically generated what is the best way to go about doing this. The problem that I am having now is that when I click one button it seems to fire the event for each button rendered on the page since they have the same name.  I just want the event or method called to just fire once for that specific click.

Comment: Are you emitting a button for each row? The click event of the button needs to pass the id along to whatever function handles the event so you can us it to concatenate with the name to identify the proper input controls associated with that row.

Comment: Please note updated answer with example. Not tested, so you might have to play with it a bit.